# How to create a segmented timeline dataset (using Objective-C)

Tags: ios, objective-c, data-structures, dataset

I'm looking to build a dataset that can be represented as a timeline with gaps. I need quick lookup of a value, so I'm hoping to avoid loops when checking if a value is in a range.

**The general idea:** I have a video where I am displaying objects (TimedObject objects) on the view during certain intervals of time. The TimedObjects have intervals designated by an NSRange struct (frameRange), which hold the starting frame and ending frame for the interval. The TimedObjects also have data on the content to be displayed (text, color, position, etc...).

**The specific idea:** I want to build a data set that holds a set of ranges, illustrated by this timeline...

[image]

Where A, B, C, D are TimedObjects with the ranges representing their starting and ending frames.

A call to this dataset would look like this...

```
NSArray *timeObjectsOnFrame = [timeObjectsModel getTimedObjectsOnFrame:15];  // Returns array containing TimedObject A
NSArray *timeObjectsOnFrame = [timeObjectsModel getTimedObjectsOnFrame:75];  // Returns array containing TimedObject C and D
NSArray *timeObjectsOnFrame = [timeObjectsModel getTimedObjectsOnFrame:30];  // Returns a nil array
```

So `getTimedObjectsOnFrame:` will have two tasks...
1) Check if a TimedObject (can be more than one) exists on that frame (in the NSRange frameRange property).
2) If at least one TimedObject exists on that frame, return all of the TimedObjects that have that frame in it's interval.

**How I currently have this set up:** Each call to `getTimedObjectsOnFrame:` will loop through all of the TimedObjects (stored in an array). If the frameNumber is in the range of the current timedObject, then add that TimedObject to the array to return after the loop is complete.

```
- (NSArray *)getTimedObjectsOnFrame:(NSInteger)frameNumber
{
    NSMutableArray *tempArray = [NSMutableArray array];
    for (TimedObject *timedObject in _timedObjectsArray) {
        if (NSLocationInRange(frameNumber, timedObject.frameRange)) {
            // This object is in the range, save it to return later.
            [tempArray addObject:timedObject];
        }
    }
    if (tempArray.count == 0) {
        return nil;
    } else {
        return [NSArray arrayWithArray:tempArray];
    }
}
```

The clear optimization to make here is to order the TimedObjects by starting frame, and we can kill the loop early if we get to a TimedObject where the TimedObject's starting frame is greater than the frameNumber. However, this will still be at worst O(n).

**What is desired**: How can I create a dataset that will give me the quick lookup I'm looking for and still be able to return multiple values? I'm hoping that I can create something that is lightweight and that represents a timeline like the one above. I'm building this in Objective-C, but pseudocode would be helpful too.

Any suggestions or ideas are appreciated! Let me know if any clarifications need to be made, or if I should provide more info. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An answer to what you are searching for is called a [Interval tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interval_tree), there are explanations in the Wikipedia.

Comment: Excellent, thank you. This is what I was looking for. However, after implementing an array of objects that have the range property, I actually found it faster to simply loop through each object and check if the value is in the range. I used this class to quickly get an Interval Tree made: https://github.com/heardrwt/RHIntervalTree. I'm running the check roughly three times every second, with 100 objects to check. I have no stopping conditions in place yet, and the for-loop is faster than RHIntervalTree's implementation.

Comment: For small numbers the brute force method can be competitive, it is often with large numbers that complex constructs make sense, and in this case, when modifications happen rarely and requests happen frequently (due to the O(N lg N) initial construction time for most trees)

Comment: Yep, I will likely need the interval tree in the future when dealing with much more than a 100 objects.